# odoo create database via xmlrpc

Tags: python-3.x, xml-rpc, odoo-14

I'm trying to script the creation a a new database + import data from other sources in odoo.
I am at the first step, creating a new database.
I have the following code, but it doesnt work :

```py
import xmlrpc.client

print("Db name : ", end="")
db_name = input()
with xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('127.0.0.1:8070/xmlrpc/2/db') as mod:
     RES = mod.create_database(db_name, False, 'en_US')
```

(note that my test server does run on localhost port 8070)

The result is :

```
$ python3 baseodoo.py 
Db name : please_work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "baseodoo.py", line 5, in <module>
    with xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('127.0.0.1:8070/xmlrpc/2/db') as mod:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1419, in __init__
    raise OSError("unsupported XML-RPC protocol")
OSError: unsupported XML-RPC protocol
```

Am am unsure of the url ending in `/db`, I've got it from `dispatch_rpc(…)` in http.py which tests `service_name` for `"common"`, `"db"` and `"object"`

Also in `dispatch(…)` from db.py, a method is prefixed by `"exp_"` so by calling `create_database` it should execute the `exp_create_database` function in db.py

I guess my reasoning is flawed but I don't know where. Help !

EDIT :

Ok I'm stupid, the url should start with "http://". Still I now get
`xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 3: 'Access Denied'>`

EDIT2 :

There was a typo in the password I gave, so closing the question now.

Comment: Looks like permission issue on database, I think you need to specify appropriate database user with user right to create new database.

Comment: Missing `HTTP` protocol  in the URL